# Reverse geocode, reading .CSV file and TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, csv

Fixed: Added float() to coordinates1 and coordinates2:

```
my_location = gmaps.reverse_geocode(float(coordinates1), float(coordinates2))
```

I'm trying to convert lat long coordinates to addresses. I have a .CSV file with the coordinates, and I don't know if my code can read it, or if it's something else that's wrong. 
Here is my code:

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
import csv

gmaps = Geocoder(api_key='api-key')

input = open('C:/Users/Steffen/PycharmProjects/untitled/sadist.csv','r')
output = open('C:/Users/Steffen/PycharmProjects/untitled/distsaretailer.csv', 'w')

try:
reader = csv.reader(input)
writer = csv.writer(output)

for row in reader:
    print(row)
    coordinates1 = row[0]
    coordinates2 = row[1]

    my_location = gmaps.reverse_geocode(coordinates1,coordinates2)

    writer.writerow(my_location)

finally:
input.close()
output.close()
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/../latlongs.py", line 22, in <module>
    my_location = gmaps.reverse_geocode(coordinates1,coordinates2)

  File "C:\..\pygeocoder.py", line 155, in reverse_geocode
    'latlng':   "%f,%f" % (lat, lng),
['69.9687376', '23.2715496']
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you need to convert those coords from strings to floats. Use `float(row[0])`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *PM 2Ring* pointed out, you need to convert the coordinates from strings into floating point numbers. Replace:

```
coordinates1 = row[0]
coordinates2 = row[1]
```

with:

```
coordinates1, coordinates2 = [float(c) for c in row]
```