# Can you help me reverse geocode a csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv, geocode

I found a python code on stack overflow here
[Reverse geocode, reading .CSV file and TypeError: a float is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715222/reverse-geocode-reading-csv-file-and-typeerror-a-float-is-required)

I am trying to reverse geocode my own CSV file. I decided to use (Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32) because I believe that is what the code I'm using was written in. This is the code

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
import csv

gmaps = Geocoder(api_key='api-key')

input = open('C:/Users/DavidDouglas/pythongeocode/BikeEvent_view.csv','r')
output = open('C:/Users/Steffen/pythongeocode/addresses.csv','w')

try:
    reader = csv.reader(input)
    writer = csv.writer(output)

for row in reader:
    print(row)
    coordinates1 = row[1]
    coordinates2 = row[2]

    my_location = gmaps.reverse_geocode(float(coordinates1), 
    float(coordinates2))

    writer.writerow(my_location)

finally:
input.close()
output.close()
```

I'm getting the error

```
File "c:/Users/DavidDouglas/code/python/reversegeocode.py", line 13
for row in reader:
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is probably a very silly question that python pros will laugh at, but I'm pretty new to the language and am trying to help out a friend. Thanks for any assitance

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed the indentation to how it is in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `for` loop inside the `try` block. Python thinks you're ending your try-except-finally block without an `except` or `finally` block when you don't have the `for` loop inside the `try` block. I think it's possible to have a `try` statement with just a `finally` statement, but it's better to have an `except` block just in case.